# Crystal Report - The ) is missing

Tags: crystal-reports, compiler-errors, report

I have encountered this issue with all of my report templates. I'm sure that it's not coming from the formula which all statements are nested properly.

I wonder do you guys have experienced this before?

The formula as below:

TrimRight (SQLcall('SELECT rest_name FROM micros.rest_def WHERE store_id = (select fem_getstoreid(*))')) + ' - ' +

TrimRight (SQLcall('SELECT location_name_1 FROM micros.rest_def WHERE store_id = (select fem_getstoreid(*))'));

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen a SQLcall before in a report formula. I'm not sure you can execute SQL statements directly from a formula. You should link tables as needed in the Database Expert. If you have more complex data structures, then it is often reasonable to create intermediate queries (views) or stored procedures in the database and use them in the report.